# function in update cursor

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, function

I have az update cursor loop, in which I'd like to use the function written earlier.

```
Function:
def TL ():
    addlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"gk25.shp")
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addlayer, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("gk25", 'intersect', "ActualLayer")
    cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("gk25") # cursor loops through feature class
    for row in cursor:
        rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("gk25") # defines rows variable, which comes from SearchCursor function
        fields = arcpy.ListFields("gk25", "", "ALL") # defines fields variable as a list, from all the fields in the table
        for row in rows: # loops through all rows
            for field in fields: # loops through all fields
                if field.name == "T_LAP": # gets the number of the last registered object from joined table
                        tlp = (row.getValue(field.name))
                        arcpy.AddMessage(tlp)
                        return tlp
    arcpy.Delete_management("gk25") # deletes the "gk25" layer from the map document
```

And here is the update cursor:

```
fc = "Kutak" # defines fc variable as the "Kutak" layer
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc, "", "") # gets all fields to a list for the loop
    for field in fields: # loops through all fields
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, field.name) as cursor: # loops through the fields
            for row in cursor:
                if field.name == fieldName10:
                    row [0] = TL
                    cursor.updateRow(row)
                    arcpy.AddMessage(TL)
```

I get this error message:

```
TypeError: value #0 - unsupported type: function
```

Any ideas to get rid with this?

Comment: Can you indicate which line of code produces the error please?

Comment: The line with the: cursor.updateRow(row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is you need to put parenthesis after your function, despite the lack of inputs.

However, since the function `TL` performs the same actions each time, I'd pull it out of your loop and just do it once.

Also, instead of iterating through each field in a list and checking if it matches a particular field name, just use the desired field in your cursor.

```
tlOut = TL ()

fc = "Kutak" # defines fc variable as the "Kutak" layer
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fieldName10) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row [0] = tlOut
        cursor.updateRow(row)
        arcpy.AddMessage(tlOut)
```